# Difference between => constant to { get; } = constant

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

In the context of best practice and performance (if any) what is better for exposing a value that is either set or calculated once as a property in C# 6+ style properties?

I'm comparing [expression bodied properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#expression-bodied-function-members)

```
public string Name => "bob";
```

and [auto-property initialisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#auto-property-initializers)

```
public string Name { get; } = "bob";
```

Does it desugar to the same thing? I can't find anywhere in the docs that says which to use for my case. I apologise if this is covered already in SO, the search got me no where.

Comment: Sadly the answer of the duplicate doesn't answer the specifics of a set-once only value, the answer below answers my exactly question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Beware! expression bodied properties will execute the expression *every time they are called!*** You can see the examples in the last part of my answer.

```
public string Name => "bob";
```

Is syntactic sugar for

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return "bob";
    }
}
```

While

```
public string Name { get; } = "bob";
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
private readonly string _name = "bob";

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name ;
    }
}
```

[Check it out yourself.](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoGYECY4DCcA3hnOQjlACxwCyAFAJQlkUC+b5XlCi8AUwByAQwC2AuAF4AfHABEAIwD2i+WnQU4PbH3gA3URJJwA5gIAuyOO2kKVajVozsgA==)

**Beware - here is the dangerous part!**

Please note that the expression body will be executed every time you call this property. That's fine when it's returning a hard coded value, but if it's returning a list, for example, it will return a new list every time:

```
public List<String> Names => new List<String>() {"bob"};
```

Is syntactic sugar for:

```
public List<string> Names
{
    get
    {
        return new List<string>() {"bob"};
    }
}
```

That is not the case with auto-property initialization:

```
public List<String> Names { get; } = new List<String>() {"bob"};
```

Is syntactic sugar for this:

```
private readonly List<string> _names = new List<string>() {"bob"};

public string Names 
{
    get
    {
         return _names;
    }
}
```

As you can see, here the list is only initialized once.

[Check it out yourself.](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLAChYMQFjZgZgQCY4BhOAbwzlrhrqiIBkBLAZwBcAeJGAPjgBDAA6sAckIC2AU3ZUA5jM7IAvnAC8cAHYyA7nDZdeiAVQBEAIwD2l86vx166J00McefQTMsjJs+Q1BXQMjT1NBSitbe3xVIA=)

Comment: well put, thank you. the subtlety was `{get;} = ` sets the backing field :)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 3):

The first one is an arrow-function and results into a function which returns a constant value:

```
// syntactic sugar for:
public string Name { get { return "bob"; } }

// results into:
public string get_Name() 
{
    return "bob";
}
```

The second one is an auto-property, which results into a getter with backing field with value "bob":

```
// results into:
private string _name = "bob";
public string get_Name()
{
    return _name;
}
```